# call a service method in background after dom loaded in typescript

Tags: typescript, angular5

I am having service method which needs to be called after my page loaded.so,that I used below code

```
ngAfterViewInit()
  {
    //Insert Details into IndexedDB
    setTimeout(()=>{
       var online = navigator.onLine;
       if (online) {
             if (this._service._isInserted != true) {
                 this._service.DownloadAllIntoIndexedDB();
             }
       }
    },3000);

 }
```

But,I can't navigate to other component while this method is running.How can i fix this.Is any other way to run this method after loading all elements

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) thread to accomplish this task really in parallel with UI rendering. You can even run entire angular app as a web worker process ([article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-with-web-workers-step-by-step-dc11d5872135)).

Comment: Thanks for your response ,i need to change my ui design also in that method.can i achieve this by web worker

Comment: You cannot directly access dom from web workers - you have to send messages between threads, but angular can do almost all of this for you. So if you use model bindings - it is enough to change property and angular will handle the rest.